# Hide specific word in a text without add new tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, hide

I have this code:

```
<div>Lorem ispum custom test</div>
```

I would hidden only and not remove the word "custom" without add any new tag.

How can i do?
Thanks

Comment: simple answer: you can't

Comment: Do you mean not removing the text *from the DOM*? Or still can store in a **JavaScript** variable the original text and showing in the DOM only the shorter text? That can be one solution.

Comment: *not remove the word* is pretty clear

Answer (score 4):

You can use mask or clip-path. Note that this is not a robust solution as you need to adjust the value based on the font properties and the real text:

```css
.box {
  /* the text to hide start at 90px and end at 137px */
  -webkit-mask:linear-gradient(to right,#fff 90px,transparent 0 137px,#fff 0)
}
```

```html
<div class="box">Lorem ispum custom test</div>
```

With clip-path:

```css
.box {
  /* the text to hide start at 90px and end at 137px */
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 90px 0, 90px 100%, 137px 100%, 137px 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">Lorem ispum custom test</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you can't do that with CSS but you can replace the word with jQuery like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($){
  $('div').each(function(){
    var txt = $('div').text();
    var res = txt.replace('custom', '');
    $('div').text(res);
  });
});
```

**Important**: have in mind that this will go through all your divs since there is no class or id  attribute for your div

Please also check [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

Answer (score 1):

and this is how you can use your Array later.

```css
var strings = [];
var str = document.getElementById("par");
if (str.textContent.includes("one")){
  var now = str.textContent.replace("one ", "");
  str.textContent = now;
  strings.push("one ")
};
console.log(strings)
```

```html
<p id="par">this one is changed</p>
```